# centOS 7 nginx 502 bad gateway error

Tags: nginx, centos7, gateway, 502-error, 502

im using VPS with 2 cores 3GB ram 1.5GB swap i been using nginx for more than year and i have not had any problem, nginx only uses between 300 to 700MB ram only my website is not so busy i get between 400 to 500 visitors a day, im using unmanaged VPS because it's cheaper, so no one can help me from my hosting company they charge 60$ month for help which is something i can't offer, i usually fix my problems by my self i know a lot about hosting this why i rent unmanaged VPS,
the problem is im getting 502 bad gateway error, i tried everything you can think off i reinstall and tried different linux softwares but nothing fixed my problem my website is not working for a week, sometimes it work for minutes then it stops and i get the 502 bad gateway error..as i said i did everything you can think of but nothing heleped, i usually dont post my problems on websites, usually people ask me to fix their problems as i work in the computer flied...so how i can get rid of this problem.. i alomost gave up.. i notice when i get a lot of visitors the problem accure, sorry for my english, but i hope you understand my problem, i hope someone can help me with this, thanks in advance for anyone who trying to help.